# Why is testing if a key exists in a hash not working for ref to hash?

Tags: perl, hash, reference, exists

How do tell if a key exists in a has, when I have a reference to the hash?  The following seemed simple and obvious (at my level of expertise) but prints out something other than expected:

```
%simple = (a => 8, b=> 9);
print  0+exists $simple{a},  0+exists $simple{c},   "\n";    # prints 10

%href = \%simple;
print  0+exists $href{a},  0+exists $href{c},  "\n";        # expect fail; bad syntax
print  0+exists $href->{a},  0+exists $href->{c},  "\n";    # should work
print  0+exists ${$href}{a},  0+exists ${$href}{c},  "\n";  #  should work
print  0+exists $$href{a},  0+exists $$href{c},  "\n";      # not sure

# see if attempt to ask about {c} accidently created it
print %simple, "\n";
```

This prints out

```
10
00
00
00
00
a8b9
```

I expect (being very optimistic):

```
10
10
10
10
10
a8b9
```

I don't expect all the ways I tried to work but at least one should.  I've gone over perldoc, other SO questions, and Googling all over, and all I come up with is that the syntax I use in some of these lines should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
%href = \%simple;
```

doesn't do what you think it does; `perl -w` (or `use warnings;`) would give you a warning about an odd number of hash elements, which should be a sufficient hint as to what it tried to do (and, if you think about it, why your "bad syntax" isn't).  Try

```
$href = \%simple;
```

Also, learn to use `use warnings;` and `use strict;`, and *always* use them.

Comment: Aha, I made that boo-boo before.  Yes, strict and warnings are good even for very short experiments.